# C++ std::sort of const struct

Tags: sorting, c++11, vector, struct, constants

I have the following `struct` in a `vector`

```
struct ub_node {
    const size_t index;
    const double ub_dist;
    bool operator<(const ub_node &rhs) const { return ub_dist< rhs.ub_dist; }
};
```

I would like to sort that `vector`. I have tried using `std::sort` but I get a compile error:
`error: use of deleted function ‘ub_node& ub_node::operator=(ub_node&&)’` with a reference to the line where I do `std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());`, where `result` is of type `vector<ub_node>`.

As far as I understand, the `const` does **NOT** affect the execution time, but merely ensures that the programmer (me) does not do anything stupid. If this is the case, I might remove the `const` and try to ensure that I do not change the node afterwards. Can someone confirm this? Or help me to sort it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I understand, the const does NOT affect the execution time, but merely ensures that the programmer (me) does not do anything stupid.

Correct.

Sorting a vector swaps the elements around, which is not possible if the elements have immutable data (with your `ub_node` type you can't even remove or insert an element anywhere except the end of the vector, because that also needs to modify existing elements).

I suggest you remove the `const` from your members, so the type is *possible* to modify, and then structure your code so that parts of the program which shouldn't modify it only interacts with the class through `const ub_node&` or `const ub_node*`.

That means that the class is modifiable when necessary, but won't be modified by parts of the program that aren't supposed to modify it.

Comment: Does this imply, that if my `struct` had a complex member, e.g. another `vector`, then sorting this would make a lot of copies of these `vector`s or does it simply change the reference?

Comment: Sorting a vector `vec` of your struct will call `swap(vec[i], vec[j])` lots of times. Whether that is efficient or does lots of assignments of your structs members depends on whether you have overloaded `swap` for your type, or whether your type can be _move assigned_ cheaply. If your class overloads `swap` or follows [the rule of five or the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) then sorting it will be cheap, with no copying.